# Issues mapping an object returned from ajax call local variable for knockout autocomplete

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am using knockout (v3.2) autocomplete and I have an ajax call that returns a list of values.

```
var remoteData = $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetAllSkills", "EmployeeSkills")',
                data: { },
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    var array = ($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            id: item.SkillsId,
                            name: item.SkillName
                        };
                    }));      
                }
            });
```

The object returned is assigned to the remoteData variable which has a property called 'responseText' that has the following data --> "[{"SkillId":1,"SkillName":"Test Skill 1"},{"SkillId":2,"SkillName":"Test Skill 2"},{"SkillId":3,"SkillName":"Test Skill 3"},{"SkillId":4,"SkillName":"Test Skill 4"},{"SkillId":5,"SkillName":"Test Skill 5"},{"SkillId":6,"SkillName":"Test Skill 6"},{"SkillId":7,"SkillName":"Test Skill 7"},{"SkillId":8,"SkillName":"abc"},{"SkillId":10,"SkillName":"Test Skill 34"},{"SkillId":11,"SkillName":"xyz"},{"SkillId":12,"SkillName":"Entirely new skill!"},{"SkillId":13,"SkillName":"Yet another new skill"},{"SkillId":1000,"SkillName":"New Test Skill 1"},{"SkillId":1001,"SkillName":"test1"},{"SkillId":1002,"SkillName":".NET v4.5"},{"SkillId":1003,"SkillName":"C#"},{"SkillId":1004,"SkillName":"ASP.NET"},{"SkillId":1006,"SkillName":"MVC"},{"SkillId":1007,"SkillName":"PHP"},{"SkillId":1008,"SkillName":"F#"},{"SkillId":1009,"SkillName":"Angular"},{"SkillId":1010,"SkillName":"Test 100"}]"

Inside my view model I have the following code...

```
function ActivityViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.skills = remoteData;
    self.selectedOption = ko.observable('');
    self.options = self.skills.map(function (element) {    
      return {
        label: element.SkillName,
        value: element.SkillsId,
        object: element
      };
    });
```

I am getting the following error --> self.skills.map is not a function at new ActivityViewModel.

I have no idea why this is happening.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning remoteData to the result of the ajax call. That's not the same as setting it to the values retrieved by the ajax call. The ajax function returns a promise object which you'll have to add a callback to in order to retrieve the values.

[jQuery Deferred and Promise walkthrough](http://joseoncode.com/2011/09/26/a-walkthrough-jquery-deferred-and-promise/)

Try assigning to your remoteData variable inside the success callback instead. This may not work depending on how the rest of your code is structured. If you try using the remoteData variable before the ajax call finishes and hits the success callback it will still appear to be undefined.

```
var remoteData;
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetAllSkills", "EmployeeSkills")',
    data: {},
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        remoteData = ($.map(data, function (item) {
            return {
                id: item.SkillsId,
                name: item.SkillName
            };
        }));
    }
});
```